# C beginner: Need explanation of error messages from "ideone"

Tags: c

I am attempting to write a program that accepts grammatically incorrect text (under 990 characters in length) as input, corrects it, and then returns the corrected text as output. I attempted to run the program using the online compiler, "ideone", but it returned quite a few errors that I don't quite understand. I have posted my code, as well as a picture of the errors below. Can anybody explain to me what exactly the errors mean?

```
#include "stdio.h"

char capitalize(int i); //prototype for capitalize method

int main(void) 
{
   char userInput[1200]; //Array of chars to store user input. Initialized to 1200 to negate the possibility of added characters filling up the array.
   int i;                //Used as a counter for the for loop below.
   int j;                //Used as a counter for the second for loop within the first for loop below.
   int numArrayElements; 

   printf("Enter your paragraphs: ");
   scanf("%c", &userInput);   //%c used since chars are expected as input(?)
   numArrayElements = sizeof(userInput) / sizeof(userInput[0]);  //stores the number of elements in the array into numArrayElements.

   if (userInput[0] >= 97 && userInput[0] <= 122) //Checks the char in index 0 to see if its ascii value is equal to that of a lowercase letter. If it is, it is capitalized.
    userInput[0] = capitalize(userInput[0]);

   //code used to correct input should go here.
   for (i = 1; i < numArrayElements; i++)  //i is set to 1 here because index 0 is taken care of by the if statement above this loop
   {
    if (userInput[i] == 32)  //checks to see if the char at index i has the ascii value of a space.
        if (userInput[i + 1] == 32 && userInput[i - 1] != 46) //checks the char at index i + 1 to see if it has the ascii value of a space, as well as the char at index i - 1 to see if it is any char other than a period. The latter condition is there to prevent a period from being added if one is already present.
        {
            for (j = numArrayElements - 1; j > (i - 1); j--)  //If the three conditions above are satisfied, all characters in the array at location i and onwards are shifted one index to the right. A period is then placed within index i.
                userInput[j + 1] = userInput[j];

            userInput[i] = 46;  //places a period into index i.
            numArrayElements++; //increments numArrayElements to reflect the addition of a period to the array.

            if (userInput[i + 3] >= 97 && userInput[i + 3] <= 122)  //additionally, the char at index i + 3 is examined to see if it is capitalized or not.
                userInput[i + 3] = capitalize(userInput[i + 3]);
        }
   }

   printf("%c\n", userInput);  //%c used since chars are being displayed as output.
   return 0;
}

char capitalize(char c)
{
    return (c - 32); //subtracting 32 from a lowercase char should result in it gaining the ascii value of its capitalized form.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: `%c` is for **a single character**. Multiple characters are usually called a "string" (I sincerely hope you've heard the term before), and supported through the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: Think HARD about what the compiler is telling you! `%c` means a character but you pass an array of characters, which is given to the function as a pointer. Does this tell you anything about your error(s)? Then think in this way about the other errors as well.

Comment: Maybe, what you are trying to do is `scanf("%s", userInput); numArrayElements = strlen(userInput);`

Comment: Your function prototype is `char capitalize(int i);` but the implementation is `char capitalize(char i)` so the compiler complains about the mis-match.

Comment: @Bob__ it should really really be `"%1200s"` then.

Comment: Siguza, Paul Ogilvie and Weather Vane, after reading your responses, I made some modifications to my code, and the program now compiles successfully, but does not give the desired output. I will attempt to fix this by myself, but will return here if I am unable to. Thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: Ok, I attempted to find out what was wrong with my program, but was unable to and now need additional help. My program seems to be having some kind of issue involving spaces. If I enter "hey man, what's up?" as input, I get "Hey" as output. However, if I enter "hey_man,_what's_up?" as input, I get "Hey_man,_what's_up?" as output. I looked through the part of my code that deals with spaces, but was unable to figure out why exactly it is unable to detect anything that comes after a space. Can anybody provide assistance?

Comment: @Siguza Well, `"%1199[^\n]"` then ;)

Comment: @Siguza [It is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). _"[set] matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters. If the first character of the set is ^, then all characters not in the set are matched."_

Comment: "ideone" supresses important error messages sometimes, so I would recommend not using it for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code hase several problems, quite typical for a beginner. Teh answer to teh question in your last commenst lies in the way `scanf()` works: it takes everything between whitepsaces as a token, so it just ends after `hey`. I commented the code for the rest of the problems I found without being too nitpicky. The comments below this post might do it if they fell so.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>

// Check for ASCII (spot-checks only).
// It will not work for encodings that are very close to ASCII but do not earn the
// idiomatic cigar for it but will fail for e.g.: EBCDIC
// (No check for '9' because non-consecutive digits are forbidden by the C-standard)
#if ('0' != 0x30) || ('a' != 0x61) || ('z' != 0x7a) || ('A' != 0x41) || ('Z' != 0x5a)
  #error "Non-ASCII input encoding found, please change code below accordingly."
#endif

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 1200

// please put comments on top, not everyone has a 4k monitor
//prototype for capitalize method
char capitalize(char i);

int main(void)
{
  //Array of chars to store user input. 
  // Initialized to 1200 to negate the possibility of
  // added characters filling up the array.

  // added one for the trailing NUL
  char userInput[ARRAY_LENGTH + 1];

  // No need to comment counters, some things can be considered obvious
  // as are ints called "i", "j", "k" and so on.
  int i, j;
  int numArrayElements;
  // for returns
  int res;

  printf("Enter your paragraphs: ");
  // check returns. Always check returns!
  // (there are exceptions if you know what you are doing
  // or if failure is unlikely under normal circumstances (e.g.: printf()))
  // scanf() will read everything that is not a newline up to 1200 characters
  res = scanf("%1200[^\n]", userInput);
  if (res != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong with scanf() \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // you have a string, so use strlen()
  // numArrayElements = sizeof(userInput) / sizeof(userInput[0]);
  // the return type of strlen() is size_t, hence the cast
  numArrayElements = (int) strlen(userInput);

  // Checks the char in index 0 to see if its ascii value is equal
  // to that of a lowercase letter. If it is, it is capitalized.

  // Do yourself a favor and use curly brackets even if you
  // theoretically do not need them. The single exception being "else if"
  // constructs where it looks more odd if you *do* place the curly bracket
  // between "else" and "if" 

  // don't use the numerical value here, use the character itself
  // Has the advantage that no comment is needed.
  // But you still assume ASCII or at least an encoding where the characters
  // are encoded in a consecutive, gap-less way
  if (userInput[0] >= 'a' && userInput[0] <= 'z') {
    userInput[0] = capitalize(userInput[0]);
  }

  // i is set to 1 here because index 0 is taken care of by the
  // if statement above this loop
  for (i = 1; i < numArrayElements; i++) {
    // checks to see if the char at index i has the ascii value of a space.
    if (userInput[i] == ' ') {
      // checks the char at index i + 1 to see if it has the ascii
      // value of a space, as well as the char at index i - 1 to see
      // if it is any char other than a period. The latter condition
      // is there to prevent a period from being added if one is already present.
      if (userInput[i + 1] == ' ' && userInput[i - 1] != '.') {
        // If the three conditions above are satisfied, all characters
        // in the array at location i and onwards are shifted one index
        // to the right. A period is then placed within index i.

        // you need to include the NUL at the end, too
        for (j = numArrayElements; j > (i - 1); j--) {
          userInput[j + 1] = userInput[j];
        }
        //places a period into index i.
        userInput[i] = '.';

        // increments numArrayElements to reflect the addition
        // of a period to the array.

        // numArrayElements might be out of bounds afterwards, needs to be checked
        numArrayElements++;
        if (numArrayElements > ARRAY_LENGTH) {
          fprintf(stderr, "numArrayElements %d out of bounds\n", numArrayElements);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // additionally, the char at index i + 3 is examined to see
        // if it is capitalized or not.

        // The loop has the upper limit at numArrayElements
        // i + 3 might be out of bounds, so check
        if (i + 3 > ARRAY_LENGTH) {
          fprintf(stderr, "(%d + 3) is out of bounds\n",i);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (userInput[i + 3] >= 97 && userInput[i + 3] <= 122) {
          userInput[i + 3] = capitalize(userInput[i + 3]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", userInput);
  return 0;
}

char capitalize(char c)
{
  // subtracting 32 from a lowercase char should result
  // in it gaining the ascii value of its capitalized form.
  return (c - ' ');
}
```

Comment: @Bob__ already taken care of at declaration of `userInput`, hence the comment `added one for the trailing NUL` above.

Comment: I see, my mistake. Still, I think `fgets` should be better.

Comment: @Bob__ well, `fgets` *is* better! But I try to keep it simple for a beginner and don't change too much, the differences to the original should be clear to see.